# wake up thread at specified time

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I want to wake up my threads a specified time. Can I do it like this?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
void foo() {}
int main()
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    clock::time_point next_time_point = clock::now() + 20s;
    foo();
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_time_point);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never should use sleep. Instead wait on conditional variable

Comment: Also consider that condition variables can have spontantious wakeups which requires them to be combined with an additional condition (a bool you check for example).

Comment: Do you have an example. Much appreciated!

Comment: You have an example herehttp://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable